# PDO not handling apostrophe in field data even when using prepared statements

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I was under the impression that PDO's prepared statements also did what the old MYSQL_REAL_ESCAPE_STRING did.My code uses prepared statemts like this:

```
 $updatesql = "UPDATE projects
SET title= ?, project_status= ?, bpm= ?, genre= ?, release_genre= ?, 
vocals= ?, lyrics_written= ?, voice_of= ?, start_date= ?, finish_date= ?, 
project_time= ?, file_name= ?, mixed= ?, mastered= ?, mixed_by= ?, 
mastered_by= ?, loudness_level= ?, release_date= ?, artwork_link= ?, 
audio_link= ?, length= ?, lyrics_link= ?, priority= ?, notes= ?, lyrics= ?, 
project_key= ?, featuring= ?, producers= ?  WHERE id= ?
LIMIT 1";



//update record with PDO

$pdo->prepare($updatesql)->execute([$title, $project_status, $bpm, $genre, $release_genre, 
$vocals, $lyrics_written, $voice_of, $start_date, $finish_date, 
$project_time,$file_name, $mixed, $mastered, $mixed_by, 
$mastered_by, $loudness_level, $release_date, $artwork_link, 
$audio_link, $length, $lyrics_link, $priority, $notes, $lyrics, 
$project_key, $featuring, $producers, $id ]);
```

yet Im finding if a form submits the word O'riely, it causes a MYSQL ERROR.

i CANT USE mysqli_real_escape_string because it expects a mysqli connection as the 1st paramater and Im using PDO.

Is the only other solution to use addslashes to all my DB inserts and then stripslashes on all my display data fields? That seems like something we would only do 10 years ago. What am I missing as it pertains to best practice for handling apostrophe's etc. when using PDO prepared statements?

**UPDATE:**

My local environment/server info is as follows:
Server: Localhost via UNIX socket
Server type: MySQL
Server version: 5.7.26-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 - (Ubuntu)
Protocol version: 10
User: root@localhost
Server charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)
Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu)
Database client version: libmysql - mysqlnd 5.0.12-dev - 20150407 - $Id: 3591daad22de08524295e1bd073aceeff11e6579 $
PHP extension: mysqliDocumentation mbstringDocumentation
PHP version: 7.2.17-0ubuntu0.18.04.1

**ERROR MESSAGE:**

```
INSERT INTO projects ( title, project_status, bpm, genre, release_genre, 
vocals, lyrics_written, voice_of, start_date, finish_date, 
project_time, file_name, mixed, mastered, mixed_by, 
mastered_by, loudness_level, release_date, artwork_link, audio_link, 
length, lyrics_link, priority, notes, lyrics, 
project_key,featuring, producers ) 
VALUES ( 'wyatt's', 'Idea Only','99', '99', '99',
'0','0', '', '1969-12-31', '1969-12-31', 
'0', '', '0', '0', '', 
'', '', '1969-12-31', '', '', 
'', '', '3', '', '', 
'','', '')
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 's', 'Idea Only','99', '99', '99', '0','0', '', '1969-12-31', '1969-12-31', '0',' at line 7
```

Comment: What exactly is the error you are getting?

Comment: The ususual "there is an error in your mysql statement near 'riley.. " which indicates mysql rejected the statement syntax right at aposteophe. Ill post actual error in the morning.

Comment: It'd probably be helpful to also post the field name and data type that you are having issues with.

Comment: what versions are you using? especially php, pdo, mysql-drivers and mysql-server? my first guess would be an outdated, bugged version - my second a configuration issue. because that error can only happen if actual prepared statements are unavailable and PDO has to emulate

Comment: @FranzGleichmann even if PDO has to emulate, *obviously* such an error would never happen as well.

Comment: @Nick and AT-FranzGleichman, I have updated my post with error message and my local server info. I agree it should not be happening as im using prepared statements, but alas here we are.

Comment: The query in the error message is not the one of your code. (UPDATE vs INSERT)

Comment: As @GhostGambler points out, the error is coming from a different query. Perhaps that `INSERT` is *not* being prepared?

Comment: DUH! thats it! I have a prosses-new-project.php and a process-edit-project.php that updates and I thought I was working on the edit code but I was actually working from the insert form. That explains it. Its from working late at night and tired. Thanks all. @GhostGambler was the first to comment on it so please post the solution and Ill choose you sir. But thanks AT-Nick and everyone else for being there as well. I love this community. :-) The insert form code was not yet converted to prepared statements. Im doing it now.

Comment: @NormanBird Never mind, glad I could help

Comment: Stack overflow is not for "solutions" mind you. It is to answer questions. Your question is "PDO is not handling an apostrophe" for which you have your answer already: PDO **does** handle everything it is supposed to. While your own blunders are rather off topic for this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This needs to be addressed.

PDO **does** handle an apostrophe, as well as **any other character** in the input data added to the query though a parameter.

The code you posted here will **never** produce an error like this.

So your problem is elsewhere. You may be running another version of this code, or have some typo in your query or something else as silly. It happens to everyone. But you must be firm with your knowledge. If your query returns an error, then you have to investigate this error, not blame PHP for not doing what it's supposed to do. It usually does. So the problem is on your part and nobody could tell you which one. You can d it only yourself, by diligently debugging your code.

And here you can learn how to do that. I've got an article that helps you to make your question *answerable* on Stack Overflow, or - most likely - find the problem yourself in the process: [How to debug your PDO code](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/mcve)

Comment: I have updated my post with the actual error message and my server info. thanks.

Comment: The only useful addition you can make is a **full** MCVE, as shown in my link. Just stub like one you added to the question won't do. Most people are never able to grasp the idea though, but nevertheless, only a full reproduceable code could help you to realize that your assumptions are completely wrong.

Comment: Yes, you are correct, you did answer my question. The solution, in case others are interested, is that I blundered and was looking at the wrong code which was NOT prepared statements. Live and learn. Thank you kind sir, and everyone who saw what I did not. Bless Sings